# How can I get rows from one table that have a specific value or don't exist in another table that has a 1-1 relationship to the first?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tblEatables (
    `EatId` int UNSIGNED PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Fruits` varchar(9) NOT NULL
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tblConfirm_Eatables (
    Eatables_Id INT UNSIGNED,
    Edible_Status INT,
    FOREIGN KEY Eatables_Id REFERENCES tblEatables (EatId)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

I want to select all the tblEatables.Fruits which are in tblConfirm_Eatables that have an Edible_Status of 0, and those which are not in tblConfirm_Eatables.

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO tblEatables
(`EatId`, `Fruits`)
    VALUES
(1, 'Apples'),
(2, 'Oranges'),
(3, 'Papaya'),
(4, 'Jackfruit'),
(5, 'Pineapple'),
(6, 'Mango');

INSERT INTO tblConfirm_Eatables
    VALUES
(1,0),
(2,1),
(3,0),
(4,0);
```

The results should be:

> ```
>   Fruits
>   Apple
>   Papaya
>   Jackfruit
>   Pineapple
>   Mango
> ```

Note "Orange" is not there since it has an edible status of "1".

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for [samples](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT fruits FROM tblEatables WHERE EatID 
 NOT IN
 (SELECT Eatbles_Id WHERE  Edible_Status = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to first determine whether or not the fruit exists in the other table and has an `Edible_Status` that's not 0.

```
SELECT    a.Fruits
FROM      tblEatables a
LEFT JOIN tblConfirm_Eatables b ON 
          a.EatId = b.Eatables_Id AND
          b.Edible_Status > 0
WHERE     b.Eatables_Id IS NULL
```

Then the `WHERE` clause gets all rows in `tblEatables` which don't satisfy the join condition.

This can be really fast if you build a composite index on fields (`Eatables_Id`, `Edible_Status`) in the `tblConfirm_Eatables` table.

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad05/1/0)

Comment: Bulls Eye Worked Like Charm Thanks Dude

Comment: @Athi, just FYI on the answer you've just switched your accept to: while it may be more readable and simpler to understand, it is less efficient. Turns out MySQL will actually execute the subquery for each row in `tblEatables` even if it's uncorrelated. Using a `JOIN` on the other hand, will make comparisons on indexes which will be much faster, especially with 20,000+ rows. If you're basing your final decision on clarity of statement, then the other answer clearly takes the cake.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MySQL installed but did in SQL Server. Try this

```
SELECT e.EatId,e.Fruits
FROM @tblEatables e 
LEFT JOIN @tblConfirm_Eatables ce ON e.EatId = ce.Eatbles_Id
WHERE ce.Edible_Status  = 0 OR ce.Edible_Status IS Null
```

**Result**

```
EatId   Fruits
1   Apples
3   Papaya
4   Jackfruit
5   Pineapple
6   Mango
```

Answer (score 0):

To include those fruits that aren't in tblConfirm_Eatables, you use a [left join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join). The missing values from the right table will take on NULL values. Your statement

> have Edible_Status as 0 and those which are not in tblConfirm_Eatables

thus translates to

```
tblConfirm_Eatables.Edible_Status = 0 OR tblConfirm_Eatables.Edible_Status IS NULL
```

The overall statement would then look something like:

```
SELECT Fruits
  FROM tblEatables AS E
    LEFT JOIN tblConfirm_Eatables AS CE ON E.EatID = CE.Eatables_ID
  WHERE CE.Edible_Status = 0 OR CE.Edible_Status IS NULL
```

### Off Topic

The "tbl" prefix added to the table names is redundant. You might as well leave it off.

Comment: No This doesn't work. It brings only three Fruits Any how thanks for reply

Comment: @Athi: are you sure? Drop it into Zane's SQLFiddle and it returns the 5 fruits you list in the desired results.